# My bokeh could runs fine, but outputs a blank chart. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, bokeh

I am trying to run some simple code that reads a CSV file, and runs the data to show an output in the form of a line graph. The query runs fine and gives me the below output, but for some reason it shows a very odd date format on the x-axis which leads to a very odd line with several outliers (not actually the case). Could someone help?

Date,Value
01/11/2020,4.5202
01/12/2020,4.6555
01/01/2021,4.7194
01/02/2021,4.7317
01/03/2021,4.6655
01/04/2021,4.4641
01/05/2021,4.3875
01/06/2021,4.3560
01/07/2021,4.3318
01/08/2021,4.3607
01/09/2021,4.4853
01/10/2021,4.6456
01/11/2021,5.2262
01/12/2021,5.3259
01/01/2022,5.3820
01/02/2022,5.3855
01/03/2022,5.2673
01/04/2022,4.9346
01/05/2022,4.7287
01/06/2022,4.6274
01/07/2022,4.6632
01/08/2022,4.6929
01/09/2022,4.7841
01/10/2022,4.9572
01/11/2022,5.4293
01/12/2022,5.5214
01/01/2023,5.5697
01/02/2023,5.5738
01/03/2023,5.4550
01/04/2023,5.1962
01/05/2023,4.9534
01/06/2023,4.8514
01/07/2023,4.8112
01/08/2023,4.8415
01/09/2023,4.9338
01/10/2023,5.1461
01/11/2023,5.6022
01/12/2023,5.6960
01/01/2024,5.7451
01/02/2024,5.7499
01/03/2024,5.6308
01/04/2024,5.2752
01/05/2024,5.0306
01/06/2024,4.9282
01/07/2024,4.8877
01/08/2024,4.9188
01/09/2024,5.0127
01/10/2024,5.2100
01/11/2024,5.6716
01/12/2024,5.7669
01/01/2025,5.8176
01/02/2025,5.8229
01/03/2025,5.7031
01/04/2025,5.2633
01/05/2025,5.0164
01/06/2025,4.9133
01/07/2025,4.8730
01/08/2025,4.9053
01/09/2025,5.0005
01/10/2025,5.3274
01/11/2025,5.6325
01/12/2025,5.7293

[image: Expected output of chart]

[image: Output Graph]

```
import pandas as pd

# Read in the CSV file: df
df = pd.read_csv('TTFcurve.csv', parse_dates=['Date'])

# Import figure from bokeh.plotting
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

output_file("lines.html")
# Create the figure: p
#x = df.Date
#y = df.Value
p = figure(x_axis_label='Date', y_axis_label='Value')

# Plot mpg vs hp by color
p.line(df['Date'], df['Value'], line_color="red")


# Specify the name of the output file and show the result
show(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell Bokeh that your X axis is `datetime`:

```py
p = figure(..., x_axis_type='datetime')
```

Regarding the outliers - check the data. I'm almost certain that Bokeh cannot "invent" any new points here. If you make sure that your data is absolutely fine, please post it so the above plot could be reproduced and checked.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, do you want to add the data as text or image above? As i'm unable to attach an excel file. I've added a picture of what I expect by producing the data in a chart in excel.

Comment: You can attach it as a CSV text - never use images for data. If the data is too large, just upload it somewhere (e.g. Pastebin) and add the link to the question.

Comment: Sure thanks, I have done it now. Maybe I need to interpolate the data?

Comment: Ah, I see what the problem is. Pandas parses your dates as `%m/%d/%Y`, but I think you need `%d/%m/%Y`. Use the `pd.to_datetime` function with the right format instead of the `parse_dates` parameter: `data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')`